# PHP don't return number by jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, numbers, return

I was unable to solve this problem and I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong

I got a php file called getTotalProtocoloByFilter.php

```
<?php
      require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../datos/ConexionMSSQL.class.php');

      try {
        $conexionMSSQL = ConexionMSSQL::getInstance();

        $query="SELECT count(1) AS total FROM protocolos_web_new WHERE tipo = ".$_POST['tipo'];

        $conexionMSSQL->abrir('INGCER_BD');
        $result = $conexionMSSQL->consulta($query);
        $conexionMSSQL->cerrar();
        $total=new stdClass();

        while ($row = mssql_fetch_object($result)) {
          echo json_encode($row->total);
        }

      } catch (Exception $e) {
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }
?>
```

And a js function:

```
var getTotalProtocolosByFilter = function(filter){
  total=0;
  $.ajax({
    url: '/protected/functions/getTotalProtocolosByFilter.php',
    type: 'POST',
    async:false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: filter,
    success: function(response){
      total=response;
    }
  })
  .done(function() {
    console.log("success");
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
  })
  .always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
  });
  return total;
}// fin getTotalProtocolosByFilter
```

And I don't get nothing on ajax response, but if I change `echo json_encode($row->total);` by `echo json_encode("".$row->total);`

I got: 
0:"1"

1:"4"

2:"2"

[image: On top number echo, bottom string echo]

On top number echo, bottom string echo

Thanks

Comment: It's very strange... No logs are being generated by the line `error_log($e->getMessage());`  when the answer comes empty?

Comment: no, I don't get errors on log, even if I try putting `error_log($row->total);` or `error_log(json_encode($row->total));` I get this:

`[Fri Jun 19 08:50:32.628225 2015] [:error] [pid 1912] [client 127.0.0.1:36594] 142, referer: http://refactor.cl/documentacion/protocolos.php`